# How to navigate from one textbox to another textbox using arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I am able to work with the up and down arrow keys.But can someone give solution how to move using the Left and Right keys to the adjacent textboxes.i have used div's not Table tags.

Thanks in advance. This is the JS code I have written.

```
 $("input").keydown(function (e) {                               
   switch (e.which) {
     case 39:
       break;
     case 37:
       break;
     case 40:
       $(this).parent().parent().next().find('input').focus()
       break;
     case 38:
       $(this).parent().parent().prev().find('input').focus()
       break;
   }
 });
```

Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cAyRs/747/

[image]

Comment: You're basically asking how to delete `.parent()` from your code ...

Comment: Add your HTML to the question please

Comment: Did you try tab index ?

Comment: @SumeetGohil: tab Index works fine. but i need to toggle between textboxes using only the arrow keys.

Comment: @LinkinTED http://jsfiddle.net/cAyRs/747/

Comment: @Tejeshchandra `focus` thing should work ..

Comment: @SumeetGohil; the UP and Down Arrows are working fine.I need to make Left and Right arrows also to work. i mean when text boxes are in a row then when i press right arrow then the cursor should move to the textbox to the right.

Comment: https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/navigate-form-fields-with-arrow-keys.html   this example is working with table but i need in side div's(bootstrap forms)

Answer (score 0):

You could easily solve this by creating the contexts in an array of arrays:

```
var matrix = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var row = [];
    var rowInputs;
    //Somehow get the context of the inputs you have in the given row
    //Let's suppose it is inside an inputs array:
    for (var j = 0; j< inputs.length; j++) {
        row.push(inputs[j]);
        inputs[j].data("row-index", i).data("col-index", j);
    }
    matrix.push(row);
}
```

and then in the event you will be able to read `.data("row-index")` and `.data("col-index")` respectively and by increasing/decreasing the index in question according to the pressed button you will be able to find the new indexes. Using the new indexes you will just need to `.focus()` on the element in `matrix` corresponding to the new indexes. Watch out for out of bounds problems though.